# How Can I Hide The Keyboard iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

How can I hide the keyboard after the user presses 'Done', or taps the UITextField?

I have put this code in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

And I have linked the UITextField delegate in IB to the File's Owner..

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Changin return NO -> return YES does nothing. I have IB open and clicking on file's owner -> connections tab, there are multiple referencing outlets all pointing to the UITextfields. It still isn;t working..

UPDATE:

I added this to my function:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    int i = 5;
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
    return YES;
}
```

Nothing is getting printed to the console when I press return after setting focus to the textfield...So it's not calling the function. Have I connected something up incorrectly? I have the return key acting as 'Done'too, not sure if that makes a difference?

UPDATE:

I had my testfieldShouldReturn function in my AppDelegate instead of my viewcontroller. My mistake....Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Does your view controller adopt the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol?

Comment: Check who is the file's owner. Do you have a view controller for the nib? If so put the `textFieldShouldReturn:` into the view controller.

Comment: Please check the answer of CharlieMezak as the correct answer as he also pointed that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. Can you make sure that you do have the delegate connection set up correctly? Try adding an NSLog to the delegate method to see if it is even being called.

...

Your question update points to this definitely being a connection issue. Try what Vince suggests and set the delegate explicitly in code. You'll probably want to do this in the viewDidLoad method of your view controller to ensure that the textField has actually been loaded before you set its delegate. Post back about whether that works.

Comment: Can you try setting the textview's delegate explicitly. It's hard to see what's going wrong without seeing your xib file, but if you set the delegat ein code then we can be sure that it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your app delegate as the delegate of your UITextField.

```
[textField setDelegate:self];
```

Set it in the `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;` method of your app delegate.

Comment: So that *was* the problem. The textfield's delegate wasn't set correctly. Vince picks up the reps while the rest of us bicker. :P

Comment: @CharlieMezak: You are right. I'm really fan of your two comments on dasdom answer. So I voted up both of them too, cause you pointed out something perfectly true.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return NO;` with `return YES;`.

This works in my code.

EDIT: I was wrong. The return value is not the problem here. The keyboard should hide when you call `resignFirstResponder`.

Comment: I don't see how the return value of the function should make a difference here. Whatever it is, the method has *already* told the text field to resign first responder. Anyway, returning yes means that the text field will enter a carriage return character to the end of its content, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: From the docs for textFieldShouldReturn's return value:
*YES if the text field should implement its default behavior for the return button; otherwise, NO.* The default behavior of the return key is to print a carriage return, which is what happens when you return YES from this method. Right?

Comment: As CharlieMezak suggests, add a NSLog in the delegate method to see if it is actually called.

Comment: @CharlieMezak: ... should implement ITS default behavior ... What is the default behavior of the UITextField? Otherwise the docs say to `textFieldShouldReturn`: `Asks the delegate if the text field should process the pressing of the return button.`

Comment: @ dasdom. Since the textField is a text editing view, the default behavior of the return key would be the default behavior of any other keyboard's return key while editing text ===> to print a return character! When you want to dismiss the keyboard when the return key is tapped, that's when you do NOT want the textview to process the pressing of the return button. You process it yourself, usually with a method call like [textfield resignFirstResponder]. This is how I read the docs.

Comment: I disagree. I have an app with a textField for name input. And what I get from the textField is just an NSString with no return character. What is this return character anyway? Do you mean \n?

Comment: It may be that the textfield doesn't add the '\n' as a multiline textview does. But my point is just that the return value of the delegate method has nothing to do with having the textfield resign first responder status. Whatever the default behavior of the return key is in this case, it's clearly not to resign first responder status (otherwise simply returning YES would do it). Nor does returning NO somehow negate the previous line's message of resignFirstResponder to the textfield. So the OP's problem isn't the return value. It's that the delegate method isn't called.

Comment: @CharlieMezak: I have just tested it and I have to apologize! You are right. I obviously misunderstood the docs. I will edit my post. But if the return value does not change anything for a textField why is it there?

Comment: I don't know! Probably just for consistency across the text editing views. There might be a time when the 'default' behavior, whatever it is, is meaningful, but most of the time it seems not to be. Thanks for the good discussion!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the textfield to return. You should `return YES;` instead of `NO`.

Comment: same comments as on dasdom's answer below

Answer (score 0):

In your .h

```
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender;
```

In your .m or .mm

```
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [(UITextField*)sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Then just link them in Interface builder to your text field's "Did End On Exit" event.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this video tutorial will help you..

http://www.thenewboston.com/?p=1368&pOpen=tutorial

Call that **textFieldShouldReturn** function on return key Press to do this:

1) right click text field from where the key board pops up.
2) Select first option "Did end on exit".
3) Drag blue line to files owner and you will have an option to select "hideKeyboard" function option

And you are done.